# Search on bootstrap table with expanding rows

Tags: angularjs, search

I have a bootstrap table with expanding rows. Each row can expand into multiple rows, and those can too expand in multiple rows (3 levels in total).

The search does find items on the 3rd level but it doesn't display them correctly.

This is an example code on codepen.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGOOBz

My HTML code is:

```html
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="domains" class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th st-sort="name">Domains</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." type="text" /></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-cloak>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="row in displayedCollection">
      <td id="package1-{{$index}}" class="accordion-toggle data-exists cursor-pointer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#OrderPackages-{{$index}}" data-target=".packageDetails1-{{$index}}">{{row.name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
      <td id="package2-{{$index}}" colspan="3">

        <div class="accordion-body collapse packageDetails1-{{$index}} + 1">

          <table st-table="beansCollection" st-safe-src="types" class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <!--<thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th st-sort="name">Types</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>-->
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat-start="beanType in row.beans">
                <td id="type1-{{$index}}" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#typePackages-{{$index}}" data-target=".typesDetails1-{{$index}}">

                  {{beanType.name}}
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                  <button ng-click="getBeanName(beanType.name, null, beanType)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="showButton(beanType.beans)">
                                        Display
                                    </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!---->
              <tr ng-repeat-end ng-visible="false">

                <td id="typeId2-{{$index}}" colspan="3">
                  <div class="accordion-body collapse typesDetails1-{{$index}} + 1">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="leafBean in beanType.beans">
                          <td>
                            {{leafBean.name}}
                          </td>
                          <td align="right">
                            <button ng-click="getBeanName(beanType.name, leafBean.name, leafBean)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Display</button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want that when I search something under a certain row it would be displayed with the row above already expanded.

PHOTO:

[image]

Say I want to search for TBLEXCHANGEMEMBERSHIPS which is on the 3rd level.
When I input it into the search bar, it finds it but doesn't display it correctly.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Your codepen is not working. A lot of errors in it. Could you fix this?

Comment: The codepen itself is just a proof of concept of how my table is structured( i. e. a table where each row can be expanded into multiple rows). The code on codepen is not my code because it would be impossible to adapt my code in order to create a working example on codepen.

Comment: Well, so it will be hard to help you. Good luck